# Discover python service in go

Tags: python, http, networking, go, zeroconf

I currently have a http server implemented in python using flask. The service is registered using the zeroconf [module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zeroconf):

```
info = ServiceInfo('_http._tcp.local.',
                   'MyServer._http._tcp.local.',
                   inet_aton(host), port, properties={})
zc = Zeroconf()
zc.register_service(info, allow_name_change=True)
```

Also, I have a go application browsing the available services using [zeroconf](https://github.com/grandcat/zeroconf). The problem is that if I start the go program after the python server the go program never discovers the server. If I start the go program first there's no issue. I even try extending the `ttl` on the `register_service` function with no results.

I'm trying that the go program discovers the python servers that where already running when it gets started.

I recently discover that the go part functions perfectly, I register the service using `avahi-publish` and go discover it correctly. So I guess the python module is the problem. I know now that I can run `avahi` but I would like a python implementation of the protocol, having dependencies only in python.

Comment: That zeroconf go lib looks to be a work-in-progress, maybe check with the project maintainer and/or submit an issue on GitHub.